# spring boot logging.file not getting created in openshift

Tags: spring-boot, logging, openshift

I want to export the logs of a spring boot application into a file in order to preserve it in a persistent volume. 
In `application.properties` i added `logging.file=myapplication.log`

When i build and run the docker image locally, the `myapplication.log` file gets created in the container. But when i push the image to the Openshift internal registry and do

```
`oc new-app --name=<app> <image-name>`
```

the container gets created and works fine but the log file does not exist. I also tried inserting `-Dlogging.file=myapplication.log` in the dockerfile which also works locally but not in openshift.

What i am doing wrong! I am going insane!

Comment: What does ‘oc new-app...’ mean?

Comment: oc new-app creates a deployment config for the application. I solved the issue. The problem was that the local user in the openshift-container has no write permissions and therefore the java process can't create the logfile. So i crearted a persistent volume where the local user right access hat und edited the path of the logfile to the persistent volume. It worked